# svn entries файл

Tags: svn, ant

После скачивания из svn в корне проекта появляется папка .svn, в которой лежит файл entries. Каким образом заполняется этот файл, и можно ли его изменить?

Проблема в том, что при открытии этого файла в блокноте я вижу, что всё, что содержит этот файл, - это значение "12". При этом в *build.xml* файле у меня есть ant-таск, который должен заполнять свойство `"svn.info.author"` информацией из этого файла:

```
<target name="svn.load.properties" description="Load svn revision properties">
        <loadfile property="svn.info.author" srcFile=".svn/entries" failonerror="true">
            <filterchain>
                <headfilter lines="12"/>
                <tailfilter lines="1"/>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <filetokenizer/>
                    <replaceregex pattern="(.*)([\r\n].*)*" flags="s" replace="\1"/>
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </loadfile>
    </target>
```

но в результате выполнения этого таска, естественно, это свойство содержит только "12". При этом в истории svn-коммитов имя автора коммита заполняется правильно, как логин для авторизации к svn. В чём проблема с заполнением этого файла *.svn/entries*?..

**UPD**

Возможно, [это как-то связано с версией SVN](https://gist.github.com/aeurielesn/1124550), но как узнать эту версию SVN? Ни в одном из конфигурационных файлов svn, хранящихся на компьютере, ни в IntelliJ IDEA я этой информации не нашла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, это именно связано с версией SVN 1.7 или выше.

Версию SVN можно узнать по файлам .svn/format и .svn/entries

Значение 12 соответствует версии 1.7

Таблица соответствия есть тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364618/how-do-i-determine-the-svn-working-copy-layout-version